# Is there a difference in pronunciation between grandma and grammar?

Tags: pronunciation, british-english

?

Also is there a difference between morning and moaning?

Assuming British as spoken in London ("Jafaican") but also interested in other dialects

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quite different, for me (originally London): /'græmmɑː/ vs /'græmə/ (the 'm' is doubled and the final vowel full in "grandma"; single 'm' and a final schwa in 'grammar').

Morning vs moaning: normally /mɔːnɪŋ/ vs /məʊnɪŋ/, but in London morning may be /moʊnɪŋ/, which is closer to 'moaning', though that in turn may be /mʌʊnɪŋ/.

Answer (score 1):

For the case of my North American dialect, they are pronounced very differently from one another. While the pronunciation of the 'nd' in *grandma* can vary from /n/ to /nd/ to /m/, and the final syllable in *grandma* can vary from /ɑ/ to /ə/ (even within the same family), most native North Americans will pronounce the final syllable of *grammar* with a very distinct syllabic r sound. There is no mistaking this for grandma.

Comment: In an entirely different North American accent, they're nearly identical. A few hours' drive from my home I can hear someone saying, "My grammar came from Cubar."  Of course the same speaker would "pahk his cah in his yahd." This was the accent of the late American political lion Thomas P. "Tip" O'Neill, whose speech a British wag said was clearly "R's over Tip."

Answer (score 0):

`graN-ma (ˈɡran(d)mɑː)`  vs `graM-ma (ˈɡramə)`

Although admittedly if spoken fast enough and not enunciated clearly enough, they will sound nearly identical.